# SharePoint Developers - What do you include in your solution documentation?

Tags: documentation

I'm looking for documentation templates for the kinds of documents SharePoint Developers would commonly need to write as part of a project/solution that they have developed.

Or, ideas about what should go in such a document.

Are these the kinds of things that should be included in good documentation?

- Project overview (often from the Business Analyst/Project Manager)
- Business requirements (often from the Business Analyst)
- Functional requirements
- Solution design to include:
- - Site/list/content type definitions
- - Form definitions?
- - Workflows (Business, Functional or both?)
- - Branding
- - Source code?

Comment: Don't forget prerequisites such as SP Version, activated Site-features, metadata, etc. as well as how to publish this solution - deployment path

Comment: Personally everything you've listed above except for source code comes from Business Analysts in my experience. Developers create the deployable to those specifications and hand off a wsp or app with deployment instructions to a systems admin.

Comment: Thanks both for your input. Are you aware of any templates or samples out there? I haven't been able to find any, nor have I been able to find any official advice from Microsoft.